Using Double Angle Trig Identities: Find exactly $\sin v = \frac{2}{5}$, $90^{\circ} < v < 180^{\circ}$.
Using Double Angle Trig Identities: Find exactly $\sin v = \frac{2}{5}$, $90^{\circ} < v < 180^{\circ}$.
What I have:
$\cos 2v = \frac{17}{25}$
$\sin 2v = -\frac{4\sqrt{21}}{25}$
Attempt:
$\tan 2v = \frac{\sin 2v}{\cos 2v}$
$\tan 2v = \frac{-\frac{4\sqrt{21}}{25}}{\frac{17}{25}}$
Can I just remove the 25 in both denominators?
I always get confused by this part, it looks too complicated always. This is not a multiplication issue like the other.

hint: multiply your result by $\frac{25}{25}$.

@Al.G. I do not understand.

@YvesDaoust not the same as $\frac{-\frac{4\sqrt{21}}{25}}{\frac{17}{25}}$

@AlixBlaine if you have a fraction $\frac a b$, you can always multiply both the numerator and the denominator by the same number. This is because $\frac a b = \frac a b \cdot 1 = \frac a b \cdot \frac n n = \frac {an} {bn}$. In your case, multiplying the denominator by 25 will result in $\frac {17}{25} \cdot 25 = 17$, effectively removing the 25 from the denominator. Same for the numerator: $\frac {4 \sqrt{21}} {25} \cdot 25 = 4\sqrt{21}$, again removing the 25. That is, removing both numbers is mathematically the same as multiplying both sides (parts of the fraction) by the same number.

It's best to just rewrite this as a product: $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c}.$$
In your case, $$\frac{-\frac{4\sqrt{21}}{25}}{\frac{17}{25}} = -\frac{4\sqrt{21}}{25} \cdot \frac{25}{17}$$ from whence the result is clear.

Sean, is there a list with all of these rules?

It's not a "rule," but rather how we define division by fractions. Any pre-algebra text will have these.
